# Java ConcurrentModificationException error

Tags: java, concurrentmodification, minimax

I'm trying to write a minimax algorithm for connect 4 in Java, but am getting an error while trying to iterate through a list of possible moves.

It says that

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>     at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)

I've looked around online, and have found some things (about updating an object within the iterator), but am not quite sure what to do.

Here is my code.

```
public class AI {



    public Move minimax(Board board, int depth, int alpha, int beta, String           player, Move move) {

        if(depth == 0 || board.getScore() >= 512) {
            return move;
        }

        else if(player.equals("computer")) {
            Move maxMove = new Move(0,0);
            maxMove.moveScore = -1000000;
            Iterator<Move> it = board.possibleMoves.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                Move m = it.next();
                board.putPiece(player, m.yMove);
                m.moveScore = board.getScore();
                if (board.getScore() < minimax(board, depth-1, alpha, beta,      "human", m).moveScore) {
                    maxMove = m;
                }
                else {
                    maxMove = minimax(board, depth-1, alpha, beta, "human",     m);
                }
                board.removePiece(m);
                alpha = Math.max(alpha, maxMove.moveScore);
                if (alpha >= beta) {
                    break;
                }

            }

            return maxMove;
        }

        else {
            Move minMove = new Move(100, 100);
            minMove.moveScore = 1000000;
            for(Move m : board.possibleMoves) {
                board.putPiece(player, m.yMove);
                m.moveScore = board.getScore();
                if (m.moveScore < minimax(board, depth-1, alpha, beta,      "computer", m).moveScore) {
                    minMove = m;
                }
                else {
                    minMove = minimax(board, depth-1, alpha, beta,     "computer", m);
                }
                board.removePiece(m);
                beta = Math.min(beta, minMove.moveScore);
                if(alpha >= beta) {
                    break;
                }

            }

            return minMove;
        }
    }
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: They do. 'board.putpiece' removes the Move from 'board.possibleMoves', and 'board.removePiece' adds the Move back to 'board.possibleMoves'. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @BoristheSpider, question involves removing and adding to the list while iterating, the question pointed as duplicate only asks for the remove scenario.

Comment: You must use [ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) to achieve what you need.

Comment: Modifying a list in any way while iterating over it will cause `ConcurrentModificationException` to be thrown. `ListIterator` has what you need.